# /etc/auto.master vs /usr/lib/systemd/system/*.automount in centos7

Tags: centos7, systemd, automount, autofs

What's the difference/dependency between autofs and systemd automount and declarations in `/etc/auto.master` versus `/usr/lib/systemd/system/*.automount` in CentOS 7 ?

Do they do exactly the same? If not what are the differences?
Do they depend on each other or are they completely unrelated?

Answer (score 0):

It helped me:

http://searchdatacenter.techtarget.com/tip/Mount-file-system-Linux-systemds-way

> Forget about /etc/fstab and autofs. There's a new Linux system around. Systemd manages mounting and automounting of file systems differently.
>
> Systemd handles mounting and automounting of file systems in a new way for Linux admins. If you're used to /etc/fstab and autofs, it's time to learn anew.
>
> Goodbye autofs, hello automount
>
> Systemd controls automounting file systems in new Linux distributions as well. Automounting is the system that mounts a directory automatically as soon as it is accessed, a task previously accomplished by the autofs service.